# jsf primefaces download file in dilogue box is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to download file in my jsf page, and below is my jsf page

```
         <h:form id="MyListForm"> 
         <p:commandButton value="Attachments" icon="ui-icon-transferthick-e-w" actionListener="#{myTeam.downloadImageDialogue}"
                    style="font-size: 10px;font-weight: bolder;vertical-align: text-bottom;width: 80px;" >
         </p:commandButton>
         </h:form>
```

and my bean code is:

```
         public void downloadImageDialogue() {
           RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("AttachmentDialog");
        }
```

and my dilogue xhtml page is:

```
<h:body>
  <h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="Attachment" value="#{attachmentDialogView.attachmentList}" rows="10">
        <p:column headerText="File Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{Attachment.fileName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Download Attachment">
                <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="dwldLink" action="#{attachmentDialogView.downloadImage}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Attachment.id.itemId}" target="#{attachmentDialogView.imageItemId}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Attachment.fileName}" target="#{attachmentDialogView.fileName}" />
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{Attachment.id.callId}" target="#{attachmentDialogView.callID}" />
                            <p:graphicImage value="images/dnld1.png" width="25" height="25"/>
                            <p:fileDownload value="#{attachmentDialogView.file}"/>  
                 </p:commandLink>
         </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

and bean code is:

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "attachmentDialogView")
 @ViewScoped
 public class AttachmentDialogView implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<Attachment> attachmentList;

private String imageItemId;
private String fileName;
private DefaultStreamedContent file;
String callID;

@ManagedProperty("#{myTeamService}")
private MyTeamService service;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    attachmentList = service.getAttachmentList(service.getCallId());
}


 public void downloadImage() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Attachment attachment = null;
        byte[] bImage;
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();


        try {
            if (getCallID() == null || getCallID().equals("")) {
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('check_dialog').show()");
            } else {
                attachment = (Attachment) session.createCriteria(Attachment.class).add(Restrictions.eq("id.itemId", getImageItemId())).add(Restrictions.eq("id.callId", getCallID())).uniqueResult();
                bImage = attachment.getFileData();
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bImage);
                file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,externalContext.getMimeType(getFileName()),getFileName());
                }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        }



public List<Attachment> getAttachmentList() {
    return attachmentList;
}

public void setAttachmentList(List<Attachment> attachmentList) {
    this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
}

public MyTeamService getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(MyTeamService service) {
    this.service = service;
}


public String getImageItemId() {
    return imageItemId;
}


public void setImageItemId(String imageItemId) {
    this.imageItemId = imageItemId;
}


public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}


public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}


public DefaultStreamedContent getFile() {
    return file;
}


public void setFile(DefaultStreamedContent file) {
    this.file = file;
}


public String getCallID() {
    return callID;
}


public void setCallID(String callID) {
    this.callID = callID;
}
```

}

here dilogue opens correctly but image will not opened please help me.

Comment: Is there any error in the log? did you try to add an `id` the image and update it from the `commandButton`?

Comment: there is no error in my log, and file content will be return my java file but it's not downloading